# How to erase line in flex canvas drwing

Tags: apache-flex, drawing

I am making a flex whiteboard application where lines are drawn  over an image
here is the scenario:

1: main canvas holding the background image and drawing canvas
2: user can move image by dragging image
3: user can draw over image, which is actually drawing on canvas over image.

I'm having problem on erasing lines like it eraser in paint. Searched evry where but didnot find a way to erase drawn lines

heres the code for drawing lines

```
 public function doMouseMove() : void
    {
        x2 = canvas2.mouseX;
        y2 = canvas2.mouseY;
        if (isDrawing && allow)
        {
            canvas2.graphics.lineStyle(brushThickness, drawColor, brushOpacity);
            canvas2.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
            canvas2.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }
        return;
    }// end function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this drawing framwork
http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/flash/display/BlendMode.html

you will get a transparent eraser if you set the blendmode to ERASER. It is working fine on Windows but it will not work on mobile. The eraser will not affect the background images.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't noticed, in eraser in MS Paint is not exactly an eraser but a paint brush with "Color 2". When you have a white background and the paint brush color is set to white, it makes you think it's erasing but actually it's painting with white.

However, if you want to erase the drawings on top of the image, you need to have a way to separate the image and the layer you draw.

Comment: Image and canvas are already on separate layers. But as you say eraser is background color of drawing canvas. when i do that it draw white lines over image. Can it be done as transparent which removes the line area